# single.page.nav javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I was hoping I could get a hand figuring out what's going wrong with this piece. I'm not experienced with javascript so I am seeking your experience instead. I am attempting to use the jquery single.page.nav which is supposed to allow my navigation bar to scroll between links, but I suspect something in the haphazard way I code with my minimal coding experience, is conflicting with it or I'm missing something supper obvious I just can't see.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Scott Davis and Associates</title>

<style>

* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

img {
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
 line-height: 0px;
}
#wrappertwo {
 line-height: 0px;
}

header {
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.008vw;
}
nav img {
 height: 5.008vw;
}
header ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.000vw;
  bottom: 2vw;
  margin: 0;
}
header ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  line-height: 0.88vw;
  padding: 1.6vw;
}
header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5vw;
  color: #f1f1f2;
}
header a:hover, header a.current {
  color: #be1e2d;
}


#heading {
 margin-top: 8vw;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 1.250vw;
 font-weight: lighter;
 letter-spacing: 0.19vw;
 line-height: 3vw;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 2.5833vw;
 line-height: 2.5vw;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 1.125vw;
 line-height: 1.4vw;
 font-weight: lighter;
 letter-spacing: 0.31vw;
}
#doc {
 letter-spacing: 0.44vw;
 font-weight: bold;
}


#about {
 margin-top: 56vw;
 margin-left: 8vw;
 margin-right: 60vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 3vw;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#aboutpara {
 margin-top: 56vw;
 margin-left: 50vw;
 margin-right: 30vw;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
 text-align: justify;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
#justified {
 font-size: 1.2vw;
 line-height: 1.4vw;
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-align: justify;
}

#project {
 margin-top: 80vw;
 margin-left: 8vw;
 margin-right: 60vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#a {
 margin-top: 93.6vw;
 margin-left: 12vw;
 margin-right: 60vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#b {
 margin-top: 184vw;
 width: 40%;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#c {
 margin-top: 254.4vw;
 margin-right: 10vw;
 margin-left: 38.5vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#d {
 margin-top: 378.7vw;
 margin-right: 60vw;
 margin-left: 14.7vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#e {
 margin-top: 383vw;
 margin-right: 1vw;
 margin-left: 78.7vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#f {
 margin-top: 428.6vw;
 margin-left: 76vw;
 margin-right: 10vw; 
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#g {
 margin-top: 500.5vw;
 margin-right: 40vw;
 margin-left: 44vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#h {
 margin-top: 557.4vw;
 margin-right: 10vw;
 margin-left: 81vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#i {
 margin-top: 604.9vw;
 margin-left: 8.8vw;
 margin-right: 60vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#j {
 margin-top: 662vw;
 margin-right: 10vw;
 margin-left: 63vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

#k {
 margin-top: 709.5vw;
 margin-left: 33.5vw;
 margin-right: 60vw;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
 color: #f1f1f2;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="background:#6d6e70">

<header>
 <nav>
  <img src="navigation.png">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#one">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#two">PROJECTS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#three">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>


<div id="heading">
    <h1>SCOTT DAVIS AND ASSOCIATES</h1>
    <h2>BUILDING DESIGN AND<br><a id="doc">DOCUMENTATION</a></h2>
    <h3><br>AWARD WINNING DESIGN <br>WITH ATTENTION TO DETAIL</h3>
</div>

<div id="about">
  <h4>ABOUT</h4>
</div>

<div id="aboutpara">
 <p id="justified">Detailed design and documentation for new buildings and extensions, drawing on 25+ years experience of design and client collaboration, for a seamless process from council approval through to construction.</p>
</div>

<div id="project">
 <h4>PROJECTS</h4>
</div>

<div id="a">
 <p>LISMORE HEIGHTS<br>Subdivision/ New Dwellings</p>
</div>

<div id="b">
 <p>DESIGN COMPETITION<br>Sustainable Small House</p>
</div>

<div id="c">
 <p>ELTHAM<br>House</p>
</div>

<div id="d">
 <p>GOONELLABAH<br>Medium Density Development</p>
</div>

<div id="e">
 <p>EAST LISMORE<br>Carport Addition</p>
</div>

<div id="f">
 <p>URALBA<br>House</p>
</div>

<div id="g">
 <p>WOOLLAHRA<br>Terrace House Renovation</p>
</div>

<div id="h">
 <p>CHANNON<br>House</p>
</div>

<div id="i">
 <p>TUCKOMBIL<br>Renovation</p>
</div>

<div id="j">
 <p>LISMORE HEIGHTS<br>House</p>
</div>

<div id="k">
 <p>CORNDALE<br>House</p>
</div>

<div id="contacttitle">
 <p>CONTACT</p>
</div>

<div id="one">
<div id="wrapper">
<img src="bulk.png">
</div>
</div>
<div id="two">
<div id="wrappertwo">
<img src="projects.png">
</div>
</div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="jquery.singlePageNav.min.js"></script>
        <script>

// Prevent console.log from generating errors in IE for the purposes of the demo
if (!window.console) console = {
    log: function () {}
};

// The actual plugin
$('.single-page-nav').singlePageNav({
    offset: $('.single-page-nav').outerHeight(),
    filter: ':not(.external)',
    updateHash: true,
    beforeStart: function () {
        console.log('begin scrolling');
    },
    onComplete: function () {
        console.log('done scrolling');
    }
});

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Gemma

Comment: You are not calling `$(document).ready(function(){..});` Your script is executing before the document is ready.

Comment: Thanks @GauravKalyan where about is that supposed to be in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply a trigger to an element, then the element should be loaded. Right now, when you are applying your script to your DOM element they are not present. jQuery tackles this problem by using **[$(document).ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**. What it does is that it wait till when you are ready to apply script to your DOM elements. So basically all the script that need to be applied to DOM should go inside. In your case like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!window.console) console = {
        log: function () {}
    };

    // The actual plugin
    $('.single-page-nav').singlePageNav({
        offset: $('.single-page-nav').outerHeight(),
        filter: ':not(.external)',
        updateHash: true,
        beforeStart: function () {
            console.log('begin scrolling');
        },
        onComplete: function () {
            console.log('done scrolling');
        }
    });
});
```

Read jQuery Documentation for better explanation : [link](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Add class to nav:

```
<nav class=".slider-page-nav">
```

As it is required to initiate "singlePageNav" plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still isn't functioning :(

Comment: when I inspect it in chrome there are two errors, one which states that it couldn't connect to the library and one about a file called query.min.map

Comment: now its just the library it can't seem to connect to

Comment: Use latest version of jquery http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js. Then you will not have the error query.min.map and make sure plugin file is same folder as of this html page. Then you would be good to go!

Comment: I changed it to 1.11.1 and double checked that the plugin is in the same file as the html page and still no change :(

Comment: yes it still says "GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: you have to add the http://. it should be `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: ah of course! There is no error anymore, but the script still isn't working :(

Comment: It still just jumps between links instead of scrolling

Comment: @Gemma `<nav>` should have a class `single-page-nav`. Also you code doesn't have element with id `3`, which should come after div with id `2`. I would recommend visiting [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) and learning [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) before proceeding further as you may solve this problem but will get stuck later on.

Comment: YES Finally working! I knew it would be something obvious like that. I just hadn't finished the design yet so the div titled 3 is yet to be added :) Thank you so much for your help!